# Linux user not being able to login (/bin/nologin)

Tags: linux

I work on a shared linux enviroment (CentOS), but for some reason one of my logins has been locked.
When I do a `cat /etc/passwd | grep "/home"`, I can find my user:

```
roaming:x:579:579::/home/roaming:/bin/nologin
```

I've got root permission but don't know what to do to be able to login again.

What should I do about this '`no login`' thing??

Comment: Off-topic, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Speak to your sysadmin, they've likely done it for a reason.

Comment: There was some kind of cleaning about some users, but I have the autority to change it, for I have root control too. he problem is: I'm a noob on Linux and can't find this answer alone :/

Answer (score 2):

The shell for this user is set to a non-existent program in order to prevent user from logging in with interactive shell (ssh, local login). Yet the user can authenticate to do some other stuff like copying files through FTP or SMB.

Just run as a root to put a normal shell back.

```
 chsh roaming /bin/bash
```

Comment: I did it, but the line continues as a /nologin and still can't login :/

Answer (score 0):

As root, enter

```
chsh -s /bin/sh roaming
```